# Does li-po battery work when it is connected to a charger?

Tags: batteries, lipo

If I connect a li-po battery to charger without connecting the charger to a USB power supply, would my battery lose power?

Comment: An unpowered charger may have some leakage current and drain the battery ... or not, depending on the charger.Either study its schematic, or make your own current measurements.

Comment: We would need a datasheet or a schematic for the charger. It may have leakage, or it may not.

Comment: @nanofarad This is my charger's datasheet https://www.4project.co.il/documents/doc_752_1018.pdf

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the charger is built.

Ideally, the charger will disconnect its circuitry from the battery when there's no power coming into the charger.  There will still be some leakage, but it will be very low - probably low enough to not even consider.

In a poorly designed charger, the charger may leave large parts of its circuitry connected to the battery.  That would allow the charger to (slowly) discharge the battery.

---

Back about thirty years ago, a fellow I worked with ran into the grand daddy of all "bad chargers."

One of the customers where I worked had some portable equipment with rechargeable batteries.  They had chargers in the office, and chargers in the vehicles to keep the equipment charged during the day.

They'd charge the batteries over night, then take the gadgets out in the morning, get in the truck, plug the equipment in to the charger in the truck, then start the truck and drive off.

Immediately after the drivers started the truck, the equipment would throw a "dead battery" warning and shutoff.

The coworker got the job of figuring out why a fully charged battery would suddenly die.

It turns out that the vehicle charger was built so that if the input voltage (from the truck) was lower than the equipment battery voltage, then the charger would let current flow **backwards** from the equipment battery to the truck battery.

The equipment was jump starting the trucks.

The workaround was to plug the equipment in **after** starting the truck.

Answer (score 0):

Lipo chargers are *generally* designed to draw 'insignificant' current from the battery when not powered. But depending on the charger, battery capacity and time that they are connected, it may actually be quite significant.

You can easily test the unpowered current loading of your charger by connecting an ammeter in series between the battery and charger. Multiply the measured current by the number of hours connected to calculate the capacity drain.

For example, I have a [B6200 Multifunctional Balance Charger](http://www.hyhcharger.com/English/productview.asp?id=177) which draws ~150 μA from a 12 V battery when not powered. This would discharge a 3 cell Lipo by ~3.6 mAh per day or 108 mAh per month.  So it would not be a good idea to leave a small battery plugged into this charger for a long time.

On the other hand, a TP4056 USB charger module that I tested only drew 0.7 μA, which corresponds to 0.5 mA per month. Even the smallest Lipo batteries I have (30 mAh) would not be significantly discharged at this current unless the charger was connected (unpowered) for several months.

However even if the current is very low it would not be a good idea to leave the charger plugged in and forget about it. I destroyed several 1 cell Lipos just by leaving them in a box for over a year without charging them, and their own internal protection modules discharged them down to below 2 V.

Answer (score -2):

USB chargers use Schottky diodes to rectify the secondary XFMR current in a Li Ion battery charger.

If the source is unpowered, the Diode is reverse biased with < xx uA leakage.